# how to check the first three characters in a record using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

This snippet checks to see if the first characters in a record following “ is 300. How would I check for different values , say if the record starts with 300 or 301, or 302 (up to 308) following the “?

```
if($catcha=~m/^"300/is)
```

Comment: Neither `/i` nor `/s` makes any difference to that regex, and they should be removed, as should the `m/` at the beginning. Just `if ( $catcha =~ /^"300/ ) { ... }` is fine

Comment: Thanks. Just learming Perl, and beginners guide suggested those switches when looking for the single instance of a value.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this beginners guide you were looking at?  It does not make sense that they would be suggesting those modifiers.  `/i` means "case-insensitive", which doesn't matter if there are no letters.  `/s` only applies if you are matching multiline strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define range for last digit `[0-8]`,

```
if ($catcha =~ m/^"30[0-8]/)
```

Comment: Thanks. That works perfectly. Just for curiosity sakes what if the record started with multiple unrelated values, say 300, 501, 736, etc?

Comment: @LeonK. you might capture these digits with `([0-9]{3})` and inspect `$1` after successful match.

Comment: Perchance you could provide an example of what that would look like in code?

Answer (score 0):

change your regex to

```
if($catcha=~m/^"30[0-8]/is)
```